# How do i show my api all json response data in the thymeleaf page?

Tags: java, json, api, thymeleaf, schedule

1st thing: I wanted to read json data from API and wanted to show in my thymeleaf template page. Following is my code:

My JSON Class:

```
package com.mslapiagent.entity;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

public class MSLApiAgent{
    private int id;
    private BigInteger tranId;
    private String clientTranId;
    private String msisdn;
    private String msgbody;

    public MSLApiAgent() {
    }
    public MSLApiAgent(int id, BigInteger tranId, String clientTranId, String msisdn, String msgbody) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tranId = tranId;
        this.clientTranId = clientTranId;
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
        this.msgbody = msgbody;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public BigInteger getTranId() {
        return tranId;
    }
    public void setTranId(BigInteger tranId) {
        this.tranId = tranId;
    }
    public String getClientTranId() {
        return clientTranId;
    }
    public void setClientTranId(String clientTranId) {
        this.clientTranId = clientTranId;
    }
    public String getMsisdn() {
        return msisdn;
    }
    public void setMsisdn(String msisdn) {
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
    }
    public String getMsgbody() {
        return msgbody;
    }
    public void setMsgbody(String msgbody) {
        this.msgbody = msgbody;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MSLApiAgent [id=" + id + ", tranId=" + tranId + ", clientTranId=" + clientTranId + ", msisdn=" + msisdn
                + ", msgbody=" + msgbody + "]";
    }

}
```

My Controller :

```java
@Controller
public class ApiAgentController {

    @RequestMapping("/test02")
    public String attaComsianTest02(Model model, MSLApiAgent mslApiAgent) {
        // request url
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/MSLSystem_3/api/v1/messages/4";

        // create an instance of RestTemplate
        RestTemplate restTemplate2 = new RestTemplate();

        // make an HTTP GET request

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
        
        ResponseEntity<MSLApiAgent> exchange = restTemplate2.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,request,MSLApiAgent.class);
        
        MSLApiAgent body = exchange.getBody();
        int id = body.getId();
        BigInteger tranId = body.getTranId();
        String clientTranId = body.getClientTranId();
        String msisdn = body.getMsisdn();
        String msgbody = body.getMsgbody();

        model.addAttribute("exchanges", body);

        return "test02";
    }
}
```

And finally my View Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test01</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Here is your API data</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Transaction Id</td>
                <td>Client Id</td>
                <td>Mobile No.</td>
                <td>Messages</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-th-each="exchange : ${exchanges}">
                <td data-th-text="${exchange.id}">...</td>
                <td data-th-text="${exchange.tranId}">...</td>
                <td data-th-text="${exchange.clientTranId}">...</td>
                <td data-th-text="${exchange.msisdn}">...</td>
                <td data-th-text="${exchange.msgbody}">...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

When I select 1 record like

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/MSLSystem_3/api/v1/messages/4";
```

Then it's showing in my view. But when I use

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/MSLSystem_3/api/v1/messages";
```

Then it's now showing me any data and I m getting error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.mslapiagent.entity.MSLApiAgent] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.mslapiagent.entity.MSLApiAgent` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.mslapiagent.entity.MSLApiAgent` out of START_ARRAY token
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]] with root cause
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.mslapiagent.entity.MSLApiAgent` out of START_ARRAY token
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

What should I do?

2nd thing: Actually I want to check this data random basis as like 1 second interval schedule and store last records to my db.
What will be the good approach?

I already tried to ready API URL using Timer and TimerTask. But I failed.

Comment: Please create a separate question if you have multiple questions. Also include what you have tried and what failed exactly.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `http://localhost:8080/MSLSystem_3/api/v1/messages`, it will return most likely an array of JSON objects.

This cannot be serialized into the `MSLApiAgent` class here:

```
restTemplate2.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,request,MSLApiAgent.class);
```

You should create a new class that represents a collection of `MSLApiAgent` objects:

```
public class MSLApiAgentCollection {

    private List<MSLApiAgent> agents;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Then use:

```
restTemplate2.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,request,MSLApiAgentCollection.class);
```

Comment: Sorry @Wim Deblauwe. It's not working. Same error.